# TypeError: integer required while defining a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython

I have writen a cython file to do some time consuming operations for me. However, if I try to call this function I get a `TypeError: an integer is required`. I am working with `python 2.7`on a `Win7` machine and `VisualStudio2008`.

My cython code, stored as a `.pyx` file, looks like this:

```
def Forward(char sequence1, char sequence2, list Trans, list Emission, 
            list gapX, list gapY, list Alphabet):

    '''
    Declare variables
    '''
    cdef list seq1
    cdef list seq2
    cdef list ForwardTrellis = []
    cdef list singlesymbols1 = []
    cdef list singlesymbols2 = []
    cdef list states = []

    cdef int i,j,k
    cdef double epsilon, delta, lambd, tauM, tauXY, 
    cdef list EP
    cdef list gEX
    cdef list gEY
    cdef list A

    '''
    Do some computations here
    '''
    some_result = 5
    return some_result
```

This function is loaded in the following manner:

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import SomeFunctions as SFunct

class someclass:
    def __init__(self, Alphabet, Trans, gapEmissionX, gapEmissionY, EmissionMat):
    '''
    Constructor
    '''
    self.Trans = Trans
    self.Alphabet = Alphabet
    self.gapX = gapEmissionX
    self.gapY = gapEmissionY
    self.Emat = EmissionMat


def Forward(self, sequence1, sequence2):

    trel = SFunct.Forward(sequence1, sequence2, self.Trans, self.Emat, self.gapX,
                          self.gapY, self.Alphabet)
    return trel
```

In the next step I try to call the functions.

```
if __name__ == "__main__"

    mod = someclass(["a","b","c"],[0.3,0.3,0.3,0.1,0.1],[0.3,0.3,0.3],[0.3,0.3,0.3],
                  [[0.1,0.1,0.1],[0.1,0.1,0.1],[0.1,0.1,0.1]])

    print mod.Forward("ab", "ab")
```

Comment: Dunno much about Cython types, but why are you passing strings as arguments that are declared as chars?

Comment: @user2357112 As far as I know, this is the cython/C way to declare strings.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not. Take a look at http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/strings.html

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, this did the job for me. I first looked at another source than the one you pointed out and got mislead.