# Cython: TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, cython

I run Anaconda 2.1.0 with Python 2.7.8 and Cython 0.2.1.
In file Implied_Vola.pyx I have defined

```
def Implied_Vola(underlyingPrice,strikePrice,interestRate,daysToExpiration,price,optiontype):

    underlyingPrice = float(underlyingPrice)
    strikePrice = float(strikePrice)
    interestRate = float(interestRate) / 100
    daysToExpiration = float(daysToExpiration) / 365
    price = round(float(price), 6)


    implied_Volatility = calc_implied_volatility(underlyingPrice,strikePrice,interestRate,daysToExpiration, price, optiontype)
        return implied_Volatility
```

and

```
cdef float calc_implied_volatility(float underlyingPrice, float strikePrice, float interestRate, float daysToExpiration, float price, char optiontype):
    '''Returns the estimated implied volatility'''

    cdef float target, high, low, mid, volatility, estimate
    cdef int decimals

    target = price
    high=500.0 
    low=0.0
    decimals = len(str(target).split('.')[1])       # Count decimals
    for i in range(10000):  # To avoid infinite loops
        mid = (high + low) / 2
        if mid < 0.00001:
            mid = 0.00001
        if optiontype=='Call':
            volatility=mid 
            estimate = callPrice(underlyingPrice,strikePrice,interestRate,daysToExpiration, volatility)
        if optiontype=='Put':
            volatility=mid
            estimate = putPrice(underlyingPrice,strikePrice,interestRate,daysToExpiration, volatility)
        if round(estimate, decimals) == target: 
            break   
        elif estimate > target: 
            high = mid
        elif estimate < target: 
            low = mid
    return mid
```

When I compile and run it via

```
import Implied_Vola

underlyingPrice=5047
strikePrice=4600
interestRate=3
daysToExpiration=218
price=724.5
optiontype='Call'
start=time.time()
vola= Implied_Vola.Implied_Vola(underlyingPrice,strikePrice,interestRate,daysToExpiration,price,optiontype)
end=time.time()
```

I get "TypeError: an integer is required." It is thrown when

```
implied_Volatility = calc_implied_volatility(underlyingPrice,strikePrice,interestRate,daysToExpiration, price, optiontype)
```

is called 
Why is that? I can't find any bug.

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985484/typeerror-integer-required-while-defining-a-function

Comment: I wouldn't specify a variable type for `optiontype`, but you could use `str optiontype` in your case. Specifying types bring you more advantage when you have to iterate over arrays or pass data to C functions, in this case it introduces unnecessary complexity to your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the `optiontype` param. Weirdly, the Cython `char` type expects an integer. You should either change the cython type to `str` or `char*`, or pass `ord(string[0])` from python.

Small example:

```
# file: cdef.pyx
cpdef f(char c):
  print c
```

Then, in a python shell:

```
>>> import pyximport; pyximport.install(); import cdef
>>> cdef.f('hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "cdef.pyx", line 1, in cdef.f (.../cdef.c:598)
    cpdef f(char c):
TypeError: an integer is required
>>> cdef.f('h')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "cdef.pyx", line 1, in cdef.f (.../cdef.c:598)
    cpdef f(char c):
TypeError: an integer is required
>>> cdef.f(5)
5
```